# Not in Condition in the SQL

Tags: sql-server, teradata

| Productid | Dept cd |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 440 |
| 123 | 422 |
| 123 | 248 |
| 1234 | 422 |
| 1234 | 440 |
| 1234 | 196 |
| 12 | 440 |
| 12 | 422 |
| 12 | 19 |
| 12 | 196 |
| 12345 | 196 |
| 12345 | 180 |
| 12345 | 422 |

** I should get the Product ID who has 422 and 440 but it should not have 248.
Answer should be 1234 and 12

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: select productid from Table where productid in (select productid from table where productid in (SELECT prouctid from table where dept id in (422)) and dept id =440)) and dept id <.248

Comment: [Edit] your question and put your attempt(s) in there, @user2885425 , *not* the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches to solve this one.

Here's one option that I think is simplest to understand (i.e. might not be the most efficient!):

```sql
SELECT product_id
     , Sum(CASE WHEN dept_cd = 422 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_422
     , Sum(CASE WHEN dept_cd = 440 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_440
     , Sum(CASE WHEN dept_cd = 248 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_248
FROM   your_table
WHERE  dept_cd IN (442, 440, 248)
GROUP
    BY product_id
;
```

Filtering the results of that should then be trivial (make it a CTE or a subquery then add another `WHERE` clause, or even just use a `HAVING` clause).

Comment: The product id should have 422 and 440 and not 248

Answer (score 0):

gvee's answer using aggregation is probably the most efficient one. Simplified version (which can be easily extended):

```
SELECT product_id
FROM   your_table
WHERE  dept_cd IN (442, 440, 248)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING -- assuming (product_id,dept_id) is unique
   Sum(CASE WHEN dept_cd IN (422, 440) THEN 1  -- both exist -> result = 2
            WHEN dep_cd IN (248)       THEN -1 -- exists     -> result < 2
       END) = 2
```